# Pass credentials while calling an API in Scala

Tags: java, scala, rest

I'm trying to call a REST endpoint using HttpGet and pass user credentials.

```
var content = ""
val httpClient : CloseableHttpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
val httpResponse = new HttpGet(url)
httpResponse.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordCredentials(“uname”,”pwd”),”UTF-8", false))
val response = httpClient.execute(httpResponse)
val entity = httpResponse.getEntity()
val inputStream = entity.getContent()
content = fromInputStream(inputStream).getLines.mkString
inputStream.close
httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown()
return content
```

Looks like BasicScheme is deprecated in "org.apache.http.impl.auth". Any pointers on how to move forward...
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given you're trying to use *basic authentication*, this should be sufficient

```
val credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider()
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(
    AuthScope.ANY, 
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password")
)

val httpClient = 
    HttpClientBuilder.create()     
                     .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                     .build()

val httpResponse = new HttpGet(url)
httpClient.execute(httpResponse)
```

---

If instead you prefer going with a simple HTTP *header*, you can use

```
def buildEncodedCredentials(): String = {
    val credentialsString = username + ":" + password
    val charset = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1
    val encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(credentialsString.getBytes(charset))
    return new String(encodedBytes, charset)
}
```

---

```
 httpResponse.addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + buildEncodedCredentials())
```

Comment: Thanks @LppEdd - I tried using credentialsProvider earlier but I'm getting a 401 error - 

error="unauthorized", error_description="Full authentication is required to access this resource"

For some reason the above solution is not working out in my case...

Comment: @Anil try with the simple header way and let me know. We can start a chat to avoid spamming comments.

Comment: @Anil btw, are you sure it's a basic authentication what you need?

Comment: Its still a 401 without error description

org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse = HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 401  [X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, Pragma: no-cache, Expires: 0, X-Frame-Options: DENY, WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm", Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, Date: Wed, 27 Mar 2019 19:42:57 GMT, Connection: close] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8,Chunked: true]}}

Comment: @Anil could you post the Spark code you used to send the request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190789/discussion-between-anil-and-lppedd).